# how to interpret metrics for my model

Tags: machine-learning

[image]

I understand how these metrics are determined but can anyone give me typical poor, acceptable, good, and outstanding values RAE and RSE?

Answer (score 0):

Without any other context, it is difficult to give absolute ranges that generalize to every problem.

I suppose the only objective ranges that could be given are as follows: 
If the resulting relative value is greater than 1, your model is bad because a simple mean model beats it.
If the resulting relative value equals zero, then your model perfectly predicted the validation data which is good.

That said, if your model is meant to predict stock prices and it had any relative error metric consistently and statistically significantly less than 1, that would be considered amazing. On the other hand, s your model were given as an input the height an object was dropped and had to predict the amount of time it fell, a value very close to zero would be expected.